# The argument type 'String?' cannot be assigned to parameter type 'String'

Tags: string, dart

Disculpen, estaba viendo un curso de introducción a Dart, y estoy intentando obtener la edad para saber si es mayor o no. La cuestión es que hay que probar con los enteros, pero por alguna razón no puedo pasar de un **String** a un **int**

Acá está el código

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  stdout.writeln('Cuántos años tenés?');
  int edad = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());

  if (edad >= 18) {
    stdout.writeln("Podes votar");
  } else {
    stdout.writeln("Eres menor para votar");
  }
}
```

El error se situa específicamente en el `stdin.readLineSync()` y el error que me salta es 
`The argument type 'String?' cannot be assigned to parameter type 'String'`

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un problema de tipos de datos. Este código es correcto:

```
void main(){
  var strNum = "33";
  int numero = int.parse(strNum);
  print('Entero: ${numero}');
}
```

La función `int.parse(String)` toma un **String** y devuelve un tipo **int**.  Tu tratas de obtener un valor int, pero en vez de usar **String** le pasas un **String?**

Podrías usar la función `readAsStringSync` que devuelva un **String** o en el mejor de los casos usar `stdin.readIntSync()` que devuelve un tipo **int**.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  int edad = stdin.readIntSync();
  print('Edad: ${edad}');
  if(edad >= 18){
    print('Listo para votar');
  }else{
    print('Aun no puedes votar');
  }
}
```

Links:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-io/File/readAsStringSync.html